# how to determine quality of connectivity from webrtc stats?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to automatically change the video resolution, if needed( firefox is yet to support bandwidth manipulation), change to audio only mode, based on the quality of the connection.

I get the connections stats through `PeerConnection.getStats`, but I am not sure what attributes to use to determine the quality. For starters, firefox and chrome give different attributes in the callback.

I do not have a formal education on media manipulation, so only have a rudimentary idea about most of the attributes.

After a little experimenting, for good quality of connection, I am setting the standard as:

in Chrome:

```
googJitterBufferMs < 200  
packetsLost/packetsSent < .1   // loss must be less than 10%
```

and Firefox:

```
droppedFrames/packetsSent < .1   // loss must be less than 10%
```

Am I choosing the right attributes? are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Keep in mind that webrtc changes the quality of the call according to available bandwidth and device resources as well. Why are you doing this manually? Is there a problem you ran into that webrtc's own quality scaling didn't fix?

Comment: but what if the video quality is so bad, it keeps getting struck, any way to figure it out?

Comment: I don't know what kind of connection you are testing on. Personally I've never felt the need to adjust the stream's quality manually, webrtc has always done this for me and it just worked. There are connections (like 3g in the middle of nowhere) where a stable stream is simply not possible. From my personal experience I know that a 0.5 Mbit connection is pretty much the absolute minimum. 1 Mbit is enough to get a stable connection with a decent quality (we tell our customers that 1Mbit is the minimum for video calling)

Comment: @Kevin well, for testing purposes, i did a connection through TURN server with TCP port, the connection is quite terrible, and gets struck a lot, just giving a scenario...

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Using a turn server means that all data will go through your server, instead of peer to peer. This can influence your stream quite dramatically, depending on your server's bandwidth and your peer's connection to it (ping etc...). The stream itself is probably UDP, since using TCP for streamed content is terrible and will make it lag very much. I think it's possible to use a TCP stream with webrtc, but you shouldn't do that unless you absolutely have to (but I can't think of any reason).

Comment: @Kevin, one particular use case is, usually inside network of corporations(like my own), all UDP ports are blocked, communication through turn server using TCP transport is the only option we have( unless both parties are inside then network, makes it lan connection). Other than that, I am just curios, as to how to correlate the stats and connection. thought of showing it as colour to user, green for good, red for bad.

Comment: I'm also trying for the same. Is there any update on this?

Comment: @Dev not much progress... bitrate,packet loss n jitter buffer seems to be the best indicators

Comment: @mido in the webrtc stats its showing packetsLost: -1 what does it mean?

Comment: I guess it means no packet loss

Comment: @mido several years went into the country since the last update here. Did you gather any new knowledge about the problem? Actually we stuck here a little bit and were thinking about the SDP - because we see the maximum offered internet speed there for each client. But still not sure how to provide a valid connection health status for the parties in the call.

Comment: @Jurik Sorry, I have stopped working on webrtc about 3 years ago, no clue on progress for this.

Comment: @jurik Did you discover anything? I am hitting the same thing, and now none of the above works for new standards in Chrome

Comment: @SamuelThompson sorry, we didn't find anything too. But try to take a look into Jitsi's implementation. We're on it right now to figure this out. When we found a solution, I'll post it here.